# Adding 3 lists together with int , str and bool

Tags: python, list

How do I add these 3 lists together by index?

```
first_names = ["Ainsley", "Ben", "Chani", "Depak"]
preferred_size = ["Small", "Large", "Medium"]
preferred_size.append("Medium")
expedited_shipping = [True, False, True, False]
```

ex: list = ["Ainsley", Small, True], [Ben, Large, False]

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `zip` function was built for.

```
result = list(zip(first_names, preferred_size, expedited_shipping))
```

Comment: `list(zip(...))` will return a list of tuples. You can use `list(map(list, zip(...)))` for a list of lists if needed.